# How to speed up Access front-end / SQL Server back-end with large tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, ms-access

I'm re-designing a front-end for SQL Server in Access, to allow non-programmers in our company to query the database.

The problem is that some of the tables are very large. At the moment I'm using linked tables. One query that I'm trying to allow, accesses five tables including that large one. The table has millions of rows, as it has every transaction ever made in the company.

When I tried the query in Access it took minutes and would not finish, and Access just froze. So instead I decided to use a subquery to narrow down the large table before doing the joins. Every entry in the table has a date, so I made a subquery and filtered it to return only the current day just to test. In fact, because I was just testing, I even filtered it even further to only return the date column. This narrows it down to 80,000 entries or so. Eventually I did get results, but it took around three minutes, and that's just the subquery I'm testing. Once results DID return, Access would freeze every time I attempted to use the scroll bar.

Next I tried pass-through queries, thinking it'd be faster. It was faster, but still took around a minute and a half, and still had the freezing problems with the scroll bar. The issue is that this same query takes only 3 seconds on SQL server (the date query I mean.) I was hoping that I could get this query very fast and then use this for the join.

I could use views, but the problem is that I want the user to be able to specify the date range.

Is there anything I can do to speed up this performance or am I screwed?

Comment: It might not be the query that's slow, more likely to be the rendering of the results grid in the UI.  Do you really need to return that many records to the user?  I doubt many people are going to scroll through 80000 records.  I'd limit the query so it only returns the first hundred rows if that's feasible.

Comment: The pass-through is certainly the short answer...  can you post an image of the tables & keys - including if each is local or on the SQL Server, and of the queries you've tried?

Comment: Have you checked that there is an index on date? It makes a huge difference.

Comment: @Remou I'm using a SQL Server database. Hm...as for the index the thing is I'm actually attaching to a view, not the table itself (because I needed to convert the ID column from long to varchar for Access to import it.) There's no index on the create_date of the view but there IS in the original table and when I query the view on SQL server it still takes only 3 seconds.

Comment: I think you have found your problem, if your query is not sargable, Access will pull all the data, not just the relevant rows. I do not see why you have a problem with long, I don't. Which version of Access?

Comment: @MikeM I'm just an intern so don't wanna post pictures, I'd feel weird doing so since I'm not sure if I'm allowed to. But I will say that the view I'm using (see my last comment) does not have an index on date, but doesn't seem to matter in SQL server. The original table does have one. All tables/views are on SQL server. The query is simple, SELECT dbo_activity.create_date
FROM dbo_activity
WHERE (((dbo_activity.create_date)>#7/17/2014#));

Comment: @Remou I'm using 2007. When I try to import a table with a Long it just all comes in as #DELETED

Comment: When you say import, do you mean link, because that is what I would expect.

Comment: @Remou Yes I mean link

Comment: In that case: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-access/linked-table-showing-deleted-in-all-rows-and/d0451a78-08c1-4667-8677-6c61edcebcf1

Comment: @Remou Right, I knew it was because of that column, which is why I made a view to convert it. I dunno if I could index that view though considering the table is updating every night, and from what I see if you use schema-binding you can't update the original table? I could be wrong there.

Comment: Have you tried a pass-through to the original table with several fields, not including ID, and a date range?

Comment: @Remou hmm....interestingly, doing a simple pass-through query "select * from activity" without any filtering returns instant results....very strange. Linked tables are much slower, but then I don't know why my other pass-through query failed so hard. I guess because it's going to the view or something? I'm really confused now.

Comment: I am fairly sure it is all about indexes :) A linked table with proper indexes should be fast enough. Any chance of modifying that bigint?

Comment: BTW, this shows you a way around, you can get the details from the user and then run the query using VBA.

Comment: Nah, I don't think so. As I said, I'm just an intern and I'd have to go pretty far up the chain of command to start modifying the database itself unfortunately. Is there any way to save a passthrough query? Like instead of even having a linked table I just do "select * from activity"? I think that's possible isn't it? My question is is there any reason not to do that? Why use linked tables at all instead of all passthrough queries? Are there benefits of linked tables? Sorry for the broad question

Comment: Yes, there are benefits of links tables, MS recommends them, they make life easy, but you need to get your design right to get the benefit. You can do quite wonderful stuff with recordsets, but SO discourages these kinds of discussions.

Comment: @Remou ok then to keep things narrow, do you think in this case it would be better to avoid the linked table and merely use a pass-through query instead for performance benefits and to be able to keep the index?

Comment: I should mention that a pass-through is insecure, because it is very easy to get the user name and password, if you get an evil type.

Comment: ... So I would work with compiled VBA, unless I was very confident of my security.

Comment: @Remou I'm a little confused, so it's dangerous to use queries such as the one I'm trying to run as a passthrough? Like the one querying by the date?

Comment: If you have used file DSN or an ODBC string with a password, it is easy to get the information, if you require the user to enter a password, it is not so bad. If you are using Window's credentials, your security people are confident. You are wandering very far from my area :)

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to let the users scroll through 10th of thousands of records. They will be lost in the data flood. Instead, provide them means to analyze the data. First answer the question: "what kind of information do the users need? “ They might want to know how many transactions of a certain type have occurred during the day or within an hour. They might want to compare different days. Let the users group the data; this reduces the number of records that have to be transmitted and displayed. Show them counts, sums or averages. Let them filter the data or present them the grouped data in charts.

Comment: That's a good point. But wouldn't that still be slow if not slower? Unless you're saying that (like somebody said above) its not the query that's slow but the displaying? Anyways at the moment I'm doing it this way because I'm replacing a program that did this, and I wanted to start by replicating its functionality. Afterwards I can look towards improving it. But maybe I should restrict the data to 1000 rows or so like somebody said above.

Comment: If you group the data, say by quarters of an hour, then you reduce the number of records that have to be transmitted from the DB to the UI and displayed in a grid to 96 records per day (of course you would do the grouping in SQL). This gives the users a better overview and is faster.